# JDI: How to pause a Java application (JVM) like in the debugger

Tags: java, jvmti, jdi

I am looking for potentially a JDI API to pause the JVM at any arbitrary point during its execution. Looking at the [BreakPointRequest](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/guide/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/request/EventRequestManager.html#createBreakpointRequest%28com.sun.jdi.Location%29) createBreakpointRequest method needs a specific location. Is there any other API that does not need a location or someway to get current Location that could be passed to create a breakpoint.

I am basically looking for a way to attach and pause the application, then use JVMTI agent to receive callback for the BreakPoint event to perform further processing. Thanks

Comment: You want to halt JVM or application? if I understand correctly, one jvm may host multiple applications.  If it is Jvm, Virtualmachine class, process method may be worth to research on for your req.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Breakpoints only make sense with a location in source.  Arbitrary pausing your application is probably best done by suspending all the threads currently running in the JVM.  Take a look at [`SuspendThreadList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#SuspendThreadList) or [`SuspendThread`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html#SuspendThread) in [jvmti](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/platform/jvmti/jvmti.html).  This mechanism would be the 'pause' you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to arbitrarily pause a running jvm with JDI, you would use the JDI VirtualMachine interface's [suspend](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/jpda/jdi/com/sun/jdi/VirtualMachine.html#suspend%28%29) method.

However, this doesn't really give you much in terms of being able to then connect to a jvmti agent; as the other answer points out, the jvmti has its own methods for doing the same thing.

If you're looking for a way to define arbitrary callbacks for breakpoints, as opposed to calling out to a specific agent, you might be interested in [jdiscript](https://github.com/jfager/jdiscript), which is a scripting layer around the JDI that lets you do such things pretty easily in straight Java, rather than having to drop into C++.

Answer (score 0):

i think `jdb - The Java Debugger` will be the best option.
please check the url about the `jdb`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.3/docs/tooldocs/solaris/jdb.html